# What is advantage of NSSortDescriptor over swift High order function?

Tags: ios, swift, nssortdescriptor

Below is example use of `NSSortDescriptor` which gives same result as `sortedByFirstNameSwifty` then whats need of  `NSSortDescriptor` in Swift ?

```
class Person: NSObject {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let age: Int

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.age = age
    }
    override var description: String {
        return "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
    }
 }

let a = Person(firstName: "a", lastName: "b", age: 24)
let b = Person(firstName: "c", lastName: "d", age: 27)
let c = Person(firstName: "e", lastName: "f", age: 33)
let d = Person(firstName: "g", lastName: "h", age: 31)
let peopleObject = [d, b, a, c]
//SWIFTY
let sortedByFirstNameSwifty =  peopleObject.sorted(by: { $0.firstName < $1.firstName })
print(sortedByFirstNameSwifty)//prints[a b, c d, e f, g h]


//Objective c way
let firstNameSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare(_:)))
let sortedByFirstName = (peopleObject as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [firstNameSortDescriptor])
print(sortedByFirstName)//prints [a b, c d, e f, g h]
```

Comment: Not that much in Swift where `sorted(by:)` is quick to implement. But one of its advantage is about sorting with CoreData, doing the sort inside the request and not after.

Comment: For a hierarchical sort (e.g. sort by last name, then by first name) you can use an array of sort descriptors. The corresponding sort closure is a tiny bit more work. – On the other hand, sort descriptors can only be used with NSObjects.

Comment: @MartinR thanks, is that good to include `(peopleObject as NSArray)` cast  in SWIFT ?

Comment: I would avoid the bridging (and use pure Swift types) if possible.

Answer (score 5):

The advantage of NSSortDescriptor is that you can sort using an array of them, and if two objects turn out to be equal according to the first descriptor, you can then fall back on the second descriptor to sort them.

For example, say you were sorting a number of files by modification date. In the event that two files happen to have exactly the same modification date, you might want to sort those two files by name instead. So you would use an array of sort descriptors, the first of which sorts by date and the second of which sorts by filename.